# Use web browser to launch windows applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-applications, netapp

I'm look for some software (it may not exist yet) that would allow me to do something along the lines of: Install the software on a server, "package" and "publish" it similar to Windows Remote App, but then run that application from a web browser (instead of an RDP connection), say from an iPad?  Thoughts?

Thanks
msindle

Comment: Although I've answered below, this question is off topic for ServerFault as we try and avoid product recommendations. Please take a look at our [FAQ] if you'd like more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing the Citrix Web Inteface which works with XenApp and XenDesktop. It's also compatible with the iPad etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HTML5 based RDP client and offer RDP services via HTTP this way. [GuacamoleHTML 5 RDP and VNC client](http://guac-dev.org/) is one solution. There are also several commercial/enterprise products out there that offer even more options like VDI brokerage etc.